# How to mix and match samples for B2C Custom policies?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

In [samples repo](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples#getting-started) for custom policies, Getting Started section reads:

> See our Azure AD B2C Wiki articles to help walkthrough the custom policy components.

with a link to following page: https://azure-ad-b2c.github.io/azureadb2ccommunity.io/docs/custom-policy-concepts/

The problem is, this page no longer exists.
I'm new to custom policies and I'm looking for a guide to how to mix and match the samples to create my own recipe.

Anyone knows where that wiki went, or have useful guides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new [community page](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c).

Also [this](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/azureadb2ccommunity.io).

The [Wiki](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/azureadb2ccommunity.io/wiki) has been moved.